# Using setattr and __init__ to clean up SQLAlchemy data

Tags: python, constructor, sqlalchemy

I am trying to clean up some ropey data which I want to add to an SQLAlchemy database to ensure it is of the right type. So I'm trying to e.g. truncate strings to the correct column length.

I've tried creating a constructor which then uses `getattr()` and `setattr()` in an attempt to enforce this. But for some reason the strings aren't being truncated etc.. Any suggestions?

```
class Property(Base):
    """
    Property details as imported from various Council sources
    """
    MAXPROPREFLEN  =  20
    MAXADDRESSLEN  = 100
    MAXDESCRIPLEN  = 120
    MAXPOSTCODELEN =  10

    __tablename__  = 'properties'
    id             = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    PropertyRef    = Column(String(MAXPROPREFLEN)) # Council reference, diffrerent from UPRN
    AccountHolder  = Column(String(MAXDESCRIPLEN))
    Address1       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address2       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address3       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address4       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    PostCode       = Column(String(MAXPOSTCODELEN), index=True)
    UPRN           = Column(BigInteger)
    Description    = Column(String(MAXDESCRIPLEN))
    RV             = Column(Numeric(10, 0))
    Empty          = Column(Boolean)
    LiableFrom     = Column(Date)
    EmptySince     = Column(Date)
    MEBID          = Column(Integer) # Key in MEB table if applicable
    Authority      = Column(Integer) # Key in authorities table

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Ordinarily we wouldn't require a constructor, but the data from the
        various LAs is of such poor quality and the Psycopg2 connector
        so strict about types that we have to clean it up. So we need to 
        truncate overly long strings etc.
        """
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key == 'PropertyRef':
                setattr(self, key, value[:Property.MAXPROPREFLEN] if value else None)
            elif key == 'PostCode':
                setattr(self, key, value[:Property.MAXPOSTCODELEN] if value else None)
            elif key in ['AccountHolder', 'Description']:
                if type(value) is str:
                    setattr(self, key, value[:Property.MAXDESCRIPLEN])
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, None)
            elif key in ['Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3', 'Address4']:
                setattr(self, key, value[:Property.MAXADDRESSLEN] if value else None)
            elif key in ['LiableFrom','EmptySince']: 
                if type(value) == datetime.datetime:
                    setattr(self, key, value.date())
                elif type(value) == datetime.date:
                    setattr(self, key, value)
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, None)
            if key == 'UPRN':
                if type(value) is str:
                    try:
                       setattr(self, key, int(value))
                    except ValueError:
                        setattr(self, key, None)
                elif type(value) is int:
                    setattr(self, key, value)
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, None)
            else:
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

UPDATE

Fixed, with thanks to Piotr Dawidiuk. It's now

```
class Property(Base):
    """
    Property details as imported from various Council sources
    """
    MAXPROPREFLEN  =  20
    MAXADDRESSLEN  =  80
    MAXDESCRIPLEN  =  80
    MAXPOSTCODELEN =  10

    __tablename__  = 'properties'
    id             = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    PropertyRef    = Column(String(MAXPROPREFLEN)) # Council reference, diffrerent from UPRN
    AccountHolder  = Column(String(MAXDESCRIPLEN))
    Address1       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address2       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address3       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    Address4       = Column(String(MAXADDRESSLEN))
    PostCode       = Column(String(MAXPOSTCODELEN), index=True)
    UPRN           = Column(BigInteger)
    Description    = Column(String(MAXDESCRIPLEN))
    RV             = Column(Numeric(10, 0))
    Empty          = Column(Boolean)
    LiableFrom     = Column(Date)
    EmptySince     = Column(Date)
    MEBID          = Column(Integer) # Key in MEB table if applicable
    Authority      = Column(Integer) # Key in authorities table


    @validates('PropertyRef', 'AccountHolder', 'Description', 
               'Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3', 'Address4', 'PostCode')
    def ValidateString(self, key, value):
        maxlengths = {'PropertyRef':   Property.MAXPROPREFLEN,
                      'AccountHolder': Property.MAXDESCRIPLEN,
                      'Description':   Property.MAXDESCRIPLEN,
                      'Address1':      Property.MAXADDRESSLEN,
                      'Address2':      Property.MAXADDRESSLEN,
                      'Address3':      Property.MAXADDRESSLEN,
                      'Address4':      Property.MAXADDRESSLEN,
                      'PostCode':      Property.MAXPOSTCODELEN
                      }

        if type(value) is str:
            value = value.strip().upper()
            if len(value) > maxlengths[key]:
                logger.debug("Timmming {} <{}> to <{}> ({} to {} chars)".format(
                             key, value, value[:maxlengths[key]], 
                             len(value), maxlengths[key]))
            return value[:maxlengths[key]]
        else:
            return None

    @validates('LiableFrom', 'EmptySince')
    def ValidateDate(self, key, value):
        if type(value) == datetime.datetime:
            return value.date()
        elif type(value) == datetime.date:
            return value
        else:
            return None

    @validates('UPRN')
    def ValidateInteger(self, key, value):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except:
            return None

    @validates('RV')
    def ValidateFloat(self, key, value):
        try:
            return float(value)
        except:
            return None
```

Easy when you know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't to this that way. There is a concept for this -  `validates` [decorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates).

> An attribute validator can raise an exception, halting the process of
>   mutating the attribute’s value, or **can change the given value into
>   something different**.

Just return in validators modified, filtered, clean data.

See also [Changing Attribute Behavior](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html) documentation section.